# Bias against questions on mathematical software?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Searching maple, matlab, or mathematica closed:yes I can see several questions that were closed because *this question does not appear to be about math within the scope defined in the help center.* however in the help center it clearly says that MathematicsSE **welcomes questions about software that mathematicians use**. I can understand that in the case of Mathematica, there is already a SE site devoted to it but with respect to the other software, my impression is that there is a strong bias against questions on mathematical software. Besides the voting system, is there a way to appeal against closed questions?

Comment: Of the first [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297047/the-matlab-function-is-not-giving-all-the-outputs-could-you-please-check-why), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444130/how-to-get-the-y-values-between-two-x-values-on-a-plot-matlab), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180733/drawing-mesh-figure-in-matlab), [4](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252438/well-formated-table-in-matlab), [5](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332088/publsihing-matlab-function-with-specific-integers) closed Matlab questions I searched, each was about syntax, not about math.

Comment: There are different questions about mathematical software.  On one hand, _mathematical_ questions related to mathematical software are OK; on the other hand, this is not a support forum for math software (in particular, question about syntax etc are, IMO, offtopic). And you're right, that's not at all clear from the site help!

Comment: Related: [Do we actually "welcome questions about: • Software that mathematicians use"?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9073/)

Comment: General requests for reopening a Question closed by voting can be added to [this Meta post's Answers](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes).  Note that some thought (by more than one person) has ordinarily gone into closing a Question, and there is already a mechanism to auto-review closed Questions that were edited after closing.  So use this mechanism judiciously.

Comment: As an aside: Mathematica is specifically off topic since there is [an SE site dedicated to it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Just my personal opinion, but I would not automatically move any Mathematica question over to Mathematica.SE.  It really depends on what is being asked.  The vast, vast majority of questions that include Mathematica commands are of course seeking help regarding programming, but it isn't a certainty.  One counterexample includes the situation where someone is trying to reconcile a calculation done by hand versus in Mathematica--they may get more effective help in Math.SE, depending on the nature of the question.